# Convert RFC 1123 date format to normal datetime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, datetime

I am using ASP.Net ajax calendar extender control to display date and time.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbxReceivedDate" CssClass="selectstyle" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Width="200" onblur="parseStringtoDateTime();"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="tbxReceivedDate" Format="ddd MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" runat="server"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

This textbox returns datetime in this format "Tue 08/18/2015 4:44:40 PM" and I want to convert it to "08/18/2015 4:44:40 PM" in JavaScript.

Below code only selects date part, I also want the time part.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parseStringtoDateTime() {
        var date = $find("behaviorID").get_selectedDate();
    }
</script>
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only want to remove first 4 characters.

Assuming you have a variable `str="Tue 08/18/2015 4:44:40 PM"`, then you just need `var mydate = date.substring(3);`